# File I/O C++ ifstream syntax

Tags: c++, io, iostream, ifstream, file-io

I am attempting to write a program that will read a text file and perform the mathematical operations that it reads in the text file.

Example:
`+ 45 35`

I am using an input stream to read that block of text and perform a mathematical operation that precedes the numbers in a function.

I have looked for over an hour for the right syntax and I'm about to tear my hair out.

I am completely stuck in figuring out how to get the streaming function to read every character until the whitespace but it reads one character at a time and getline is not even a recognizable function which I thought would help my cause.

This is what I'm using which reads one char at a time

```
char ch; 
inFile >> ch;
```

What is the correct syntax to command the instream to read a block of text until it reaches whitespace, and could anyone suggest how would I go by adding the numbers together from the text file?

Comment: Why is `getline()` not recognizable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you're fixated on using a block of text rather than just reading in the values?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istringstream inf("   +  42   100");
    char op;
    int num1, num2;
    inf >> op >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Op: " << op << endl;
    cout << "Num1: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "Num2: " << num2 << endl;

    // pin the op-char to the first operand
    istringstream inf2("-43 101");
    inf2 >> op >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Op: " << op << endl;
    cout << "Num1: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "Num2: " << num2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Op: +
Num1: 42
Num2: 100
Op: -
Num1: 43
Num2: 101
```

If you want to do this with an input file guaranteed to have only an op and two operands per line it would be something like this:

```
ifstream inf(fname);
char op;
int o1, o2;
while (inf >> op >> o1 >> o2)
{
    // use your op and operands here.
    // switch (op)... etc.
}
```